"Unsafe App Blocked" message on new APK while existing APK does not show this message
I have an Android App (APK) that I have created sometime in April 2024. This app is not on Google Play.
It is installed by the APK itself by users (businesses , not private users)
The App created in April is fine and working good
Now I have compiled a new version lately with the same configuration
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 27
        versionName "3.2.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } 

and now when I install this new APK I get this "Unsafe App Blocked" message and in order to install I have to click on "Install Anyway".
Not clear to me what was changed between April and now. I am compiling the APK on the same PC that I used to use before.
I know that the "targetSdkVersion" is fairly old but I don't want to change that if I don't have to. Changing it will force me to re-test everything again


"Not clear to me what was changed between April and now." The Android version of your device or emulator(?) That does have an effect.

compileSdkVersion 34 will you add

When I use the SAME device with the APK compiled on APRIL I get no warnings. So I assumed there is something in the APK itself no?

Google have been slowing increasing the requirements for compileSdkVersion as new Android versions come out.
They have also been adding hurdles your app needs to go through to side load an App (They would prefer the walled garden approach of Apple so they can make more money).
This is probably caused by a a Google Play Store Update to the device.
You can turn off some of these hurdles by going in to Google Play Store App. At the Top right tap the profile icon. Tap "Play Protect" and the Tap the settings icon.
You can then you can turn off scanning of apps with Play Protect and also the sending of you app to Google.
Turning Play Store protect might stop this dialog or you might just have to accept it as part of the changes Google are making to Android.

When I use the SAME device with the APK compiled on APRIL I get no warnings. So I assumed there is something in the APK itself no?

It's probably based on the build time, those built and packaged before the policy change don't get the warning, those built after the requirement change do get the warning. May be try setting your computer date back to April and building it again, you might be able to work around the checks.

I've removed android.defaultConfig.targetSdk altogether, due to a misleading deprecation notice in Gradle, which brought me here. Adding targetSdk back in made the warning disappear.
Therefore this is quite likely related to the minimum required Android API levels:

minSdkVersion 22 should be minSdk 22
targetSdkVersion 29 should be targetSdk 33 34 35
compileSdkVersion 29 should be compileSdk 33 34 35

The current versions are Gradle 8.12 and AGP 8.7.3, required to build for these API levels.

See the documentation:

Developer Guidance for Google Play Protect Warnings

Meet Google Play's target API level requirement


